# difference between V-てばかりいる and V-てばかりだ?

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between V-てばかりいる and V-てばかりだ?. I came across these sentences and they seem to have all the same meaning "always/only be doing something", but their usage and constructions appear to be different:

> "幸子ちゃんは、毎日食べてばかりです。"
>   "幸子ちゃんは、遊んでばかりいます。"
>   "幸子ちゃんは、泣いてばかりいて、何も話そうとしない。"

Comment: Note that none of your examples is of the form "てばかりする”, which is ungrammatical.

Comment: As you say, they share the same meaning with different constructions.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference that I think might be worth mentioning is that:

> 「～～てばかり+ **いる/います**」

sounds ***slightly*** more formal and/or objectively observed than:

> 「～～てばかり + **だ/です**」

which could tend to sound ***slightly*** more subjectively observed, emotional, exclamatory, etc.

The difference would mostly be minimal unless these phrases are qualified by other words used in the context.